# 'Point' object has no attribute 'point'

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am working with the below code for ArcGIS and what I am guessing is a simple error I am making. The aim is the find the tangent to the midpoint of several line segments and then plot a line perpendicular to these points. The final step of plotting the new point the join the line to is giving me the error 'Point' object has no attribute 'point'. I understand what the error is saying but am having trouble fixing it.

```py
from math import atan2, pi
import arcpy as arc
input_shp = 'C:/Users/agood/OneDrive - USN/Python/Paper 1 Analysis/Python/Meltwater Tran_SplitLineAtPo.shp'

e = 1e-10 #epsilon

Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(input_shp)
for feature in Cursor:
    Midpoint = feature.shape.positionAlongLine(0.5,True).firstPoint #find midpoint along each line segment
   
    
    #getpoints immediately before and after midpoint
    before = feature.shape.positionAlongLine(0.5-e,True).firstPoint 
    after = feature.shape.positionAlongLine(0.5+e,True).firstPoint
    
    dX = after.X - before.X
    dY = after.Y - before.Y
    
    #return angle of midpoint section. We will plot a line at 90 degrees from this angle. 
    angle = atan2(dX, dY)* 180/pi
    
    newpoint=Midpoint.point.pointFromAngleAndDistance(angle + 90, 400)
```

Comment: is Midpoint already a Point object? try remove the .point and go for Midpoint.pointFromAngleAndDistance(angle + 90, 400)

Comment: A`PointGeomerty` has that method, not a `Point`.

Answer (score 8):

There's a bunch of problems here, and the first is failure to use a DA SearchCursor (old-style cursors are kludgey and not to be used in new code). Your variable naming also violates best practice (as defined by [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)) -- Only classes should be named in `Uppercase` (using `lowercase` for instance variables makes the code more readable to others).

If your features are single-part  `Polyline` objects, you can use the `.centroid` property to obtain the midpoint (which returns a `Point`).

`Point` is just a wrapper class for X/Y/Z/M values. The `PointGeometry` class (which is a subclass of `Geometry`) supports the method `.pointFromAngleAndDistance()`.

The `PointGeometry` constructor requires a `SpatialReference`, which can be extracted from the source feature class.

Putting it all together (but untested):

```py
from math import atan2, pi
import arcpy as arc
input_shp = 'C:/Users/agood/OneDrive - USN/Python/Paper 1 Analysis/Python/Meltwater Tran_SplitLineAtPo.shp'

e = 1e-10 #epsilon

sr = arcpy.Describe(input_shp).spatialReference

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_shp,['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        polyline = row[0]
        midpoint = arcpy.PointGeometry(polyline.positionAlongLine(0.5,True).firstPoint,sr) #find midpoint along each line segment
      
        #getpoints immediately before and after midpoint
        before = polyline.positionAlongLine(0.5-e,True).firstPoint 
        after = polyline.positionAlongLine(0.5+e,True).firstPoint
    
        dX = after.X - before.X
        dY = after.Y - before.Y
    
        #return angle of midpoint section. We will plot a line at 90 degrees from this angle. 
        angle = atan2(dX, dY)* 180/pi
    
        newpoint = midpoint.pointFromAngleAndDistance(angle + 90, 400)
```

Note that it may be unwise to assume that the *epsilon* offsets from the midpoint are within the segment containing the midpoint (which could mess up your angle calculation), and that Cartesian constructions with angular units (as in a geographic coordinate system) are likely to produce incorrect results.